# How to stop the animation of GIF Image in Recyclerview in android

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin, animated-gif

I had to use GIF image in RecyclerView.In first position GIF is playing. then i moving to the next items.then previous GIF image will should be stop. How to solve this task.

Answer (score 0):

use the `getDrawable()`method to get the `GifDrawable` object and call the `stop()` method:

```
((GifDrawable)buttonGifImage.getDrawable()).stop()
```

or since you have setup as background resource:

```
buttonGifImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gifImage);
```

use: `((GifDrawable)buttonGifImage.getBackground()).stop()`